# How to run a python script parallely and efficiently using multithreading/multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a python script child.py, which is to be called by some other script main.py
For one iteration of execution, child.py takes **nearly 400ms**

Now I want to execute multiple instances of child.py at the same time (parallely). I used **multiprocessing** module to create multiple processes, by putting the calling in a for loop.

When I run one iteration it took, 400ms. But when I increased the number of iterations in for loop, the execution time also increases in nearly multiples of 400ms.

So it seems like execution is happening in a synchronous manner, instead of parallel execution.

I verified the execution time by putting time stamps in my logging file.

Is there any way to achieve the execution time nearly 400ms, even for large number of parallel executions of the script ?

---

Here is my script :

```
 for device in device_list:
            q= Queue.Queue()
            p =Process(target=get_current_value,
                       args=(q,),
                       kwargs=
                            {
                                    'device': device,
                                    'service_list': service_list,
                                    'data_source_list': data_source_list}
                            )
            p.start()
            p.join()
            logger.debug('data_source_list :'+ pformat(g.get()))
```

**get_current_value** is the function in script child.py, which is being called

Comment: You're asking us to debug your code, without showing us any of your code? How do you expect this to work? You're almost certainly doing something wrong in your code, but there are so many things you could be doing wrong that nobody's going to try to guess every possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `p.join()` on every iteration of your for loop, which means you're starting one process, waiting for it to finish,  then moving on to the next process. So you're not really doing anything in parallel. Remove the call to `p.join()` and you should get actual concurrent execution.

```
 for device in device_list:
     q = Queue.Queue()
     p = Process(target=get_current_value,
                 args=(q,),
                 kwargs=
                 {
                     'device': device,
                     'service_list': service_list,
                      'data_source_list': data_source_list}
                 )
     p.start()
     #p.join()
```

Comment: Oh!!...really ?? I thought p.join() would make all the subsequent subprocesses to wait, but not the single proess.